# OpenSSL Encryption / Decryption php

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, php-7.2

I am doing encryption which is working good but with same method I am doing decryption I am getting blank string not getting decryption string. I am using method **AES-256-ECB** and key is hexadecimal so I pass as

> $key = pack('H*','xxxxxxxxxxxx');

Encryption is going correct but decryption is not working. Please help me what I am doing wrong.

```
function encrypt(string $data, string $key, string $method): string
{
    $ivSize = openssl_cipher_iv_length($method);
        $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivSize);
        $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($data, $method, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    $encrypted = strtoupper(implode(null, unpack('H*', $encrypted)));
    return $encrypted;
}

function decrypt(string $data, string $key, string $method): string
{

    $data = pack('H*', $data);
    $ivSize = openssl_cipher_iv_length($method);  
        $iv = $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivSize);
    $decrypted = openssl_decrypt($data, $method, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv); 
    return trim($decrypted);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your functions are working perfectly for me with the following code:

```
$key = pack('H*','aaaaaaaaaaaaa');
$method = 'aes-256-ecb';
$encrypted = encrypt('test string', $key, $method);
$decrypted = decrypt($encrypted, $key.'a', $method);

echo $decrypted; // Output: 'test string'
```

Since you're getting an empty string for decryption, this means that you've either got the wrong key or cipher text when decrypting. Make sure the key you are using for decryption is exactly the same as the key you're using for encryption, including any manipulations done on it, such as the `pack()` function you've done here. Even one byte difference and you're not going to be able to decrypt.

Also make sure neither the key nor the cipher text are being truncated when they are stored. If using a database and the column type is too small for what you are trying to store, it will truncate the values.

Comment: Per the PHP Documentation example: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-get-cipher-methods.php, ECB method(s) should be avoided